# Evaluating keyword inside a for loop in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to use "exit for loop" in checking an Api availability

```
sleep till Rest api
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    20
        Sleep    5s till rest api is available
        Exit For Loop If Rest Api  == True       
        Log to Console  try again in 5 sec 
    END
```

When I try to execute this the exit for loop statement fails to recognise the Rest Api as another keyword and it throws an error like " no keyword named Exit For Loop If Rest Api ". Can we evaluate a keyword to exit from for loop instead of just variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we evaluate a keyword to exit from for loop instead of just variables?

No, you can't. The documentation clearly states that [Exit for loop if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Exit%20For%20Loop%20If) requires a boolean expression. You will need to call the keyword first and save the result.  You can then use the result as the expression.